# Create blinking countdown timer in CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a blinking countdown timer, starting it at 5 seconds, and disappearing when it gets to 0.

CSS:

```
.blinky {
    transition: 1s opacity;
    -moz-transition: 1s opacity;
    -webkit-transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="countdown" class="blinky">
```

JS:

```
const cdStart = 5;
countdown.innerHTML = cdStart;
countdown.style.opacity = 0;
for (var i = cdStart - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    setTimeout(
        (x) => {
            countdownTime.innerHTML = x;
            countdown.classList.remove('blinky');
            countdown.style.opacity = 1;
            countdown.classList.add('blinky');
            countdown.style.opacity = 0;
        },
        1000 * (cdStart - i),
        i
    );
}
```

What I want this to do is to show 5, fade out, 4, fade out, 3, fade out, 2, fade out, 1, fade out. When a new number is shown on the timer, I want it to show up instantly, and not fade back in. For that reason, I remove the "blinky" class before I set the opacity to 1, then add it back in before setting opacity to 0.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work - 5 shows up and fades out, and then nothing else shows up. If I remove the manipulation of countdown's style (and just set the innerHTML in the for loop), I see that the timer displays properly (counts down from 3 to 1), so that's working.

I thought, maybe the browser is having trouble removing a class and then immediately adding it back in, so I separated those events by a bit:

CSS:

```
.blinky {
    transition: .9s opacity;
    -moz-transition: .9s opacity;
    -webkit-transition: .9s opacity;
}
```

JS:

```
const cdStart = 5;
countdownTime.innerHTML = cdStart;
countdown.style.opacity = 0;
for (var i = cdStart - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    setTimeout(
        (x) => {
            countdownTime.innerHTML = x;
            countdown.classList.remove('blinky');
            countdown.style.opacity = '';
        },
        1000 * (cdStart - i),
        i
    );
    setTimeout(() => {
        countdown.classList.add('blinky');
        countdown.style.opacity = 0;
    }, 1000 * (cdStart - i) + 100);
}
```

This one was closer - I saw 5, fade out, then nothing for a bit, and 1 came in and then faded out.

Is there a more reliable way to get the desired behavior here?

Comment: Is this a static timer or do you need control with js? I'll whip up something similar with js :) this could be done for static timers with just css

Comment: [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3x46d1h/2/) Already does what you want .. That is your second option just put in a document ready wrapper ..  And I changed the 1 to a 0 in the for loop to get the 5 to display correctly ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understood correctly :

```js
let clock = document.getElementById('seconds');
let secondsRemaining = 5;
clock.innerText = secondsRemaining;
clock.classList.add('animation');
const myInterval = setInterval(()=>{
secondsRemaining--;
clock.innerText = secondsRemaining;
if(!secondsRemaining)
   stopAnimation();
},1000)
function stopAnimation(){
 clock.classList.remove('animation');
 clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

```css
.clock{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.animation{
  animation:1s fade-out ease;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
#seconds{
font-size:10rem;
}
@keyframes fade-out{
from{opacity:1}
99%{opacity:0}
to{opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="clock">
<span id="seconds"></span>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

With CSS Animations you can create the *fade-out* for every second that is changed in the counter.

Add an animation with 5 iterations and listen for the `animationiteration` and `animationend` events. These events are fired for every time the animation plays and restarts, and for when the animation is finished.

Change the count and update the `textContent` of the countdown in both event handlers. Remove the `.blinky` class after the animation has ended.

```js
const countdown = document.querySelector('#countdown');
let count = 5;

function updateCount() {
  countdown.textContent = --count;
}

function removeBlinky() {
  countdown.classList.remove('blinky');
}

countdown.textContent = count;
countdown.addEventListener('animationiteration', updateCount);
countdown.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  updateCount();
  removeBlinky();
});
```

```css
@keyframes blink-out {
  0%, 25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#countdown {
  font-size: 48px;
}

.blinky {
  animation: blink-out 1s ease-out forwards 5;
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown" class="blinky"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using async functions and css transition to control fading.

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
const $ = str => document.querySelector(str);
const btn = $("button");
const number = $(".number");
const DELAY_TIME = 1000;

async function changeNumber(newVal) {
    number.classList.add("fade");
    await wait(DELAY_TIME);
    number.textContent = newVal;
    number.classList.remove("fade");
    await wait(DELAY_TIME);

}

async function countFrom(n) {
  const STARTING_VALUE = n;
  number.textContent = STARTING_VALUE;
  await wait(DELAY_TIME);
  for (let counterVal = STARTING_VALUE - 1; counterVal >= 0; counterVal--) {
    await changeNumber(counterVal);
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  btn.disabled = true;
  await countFrom(5);
  btn.disabled = false;
});
```

```css
.timer {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;

  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 5px solid lightgreen;
}

.number {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: monospace;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.number.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <span class="number"></span>
</div>
<br />
<button>count from 5!</button>
```